# Question on double inequality with radicals

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, radicals

A really simple question, but I thought I'd ask anyway. Does $n<x^n<(n+1)$ imply $\sqrt[n] n < x < \sqrt[n] {n+1}$?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in general, but yes if $x\geq 0$.

Otherwise, take
$$
2 < x^2 < 3
$$
with $x = \frac{3}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that square roots, 4th roots, 6th roots etc. can turn numbers from positive to negative; if it is so, then NO. But if the root is uniquely defined as mapping positive numbers to positive, then YES.

Comment: The question of the square root is not actually the issue here: $x$ is given from the start, and the inequality is given wrt $x^n$ -- there is no "taking the root of $x^n$ to get the second inequality." This would have been the case if the question had been "Given $n < x < n+1$, do we have $\sqrt[n]{n} < \sqrt[n]{x} < \sqrt[n]{n+1}$?"

Comment: Basically I am asking: Is $\sqrt[n] n < x < \sqrt[n] {n+1}$ true, given that $n<x^n<(n+1)$ is true? So $n<x^n<(n+1)$ is a given fact here.

Comment: Yes. And that only holds if $x\geq 0$ (my comment is wrt the fact that there is no $n$-root of $x^n$ taken here. $x$ is given in the question.)